# Rendering plain text in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using render :plain => "some text" and It's working fine.

But as the text gets longer, I wish to place the text in an erb file (e.g. sometext.text.erb) and render the text.erb.

I have a sometext.text.erb in the view folder. But render method doesn't seem to detect it.

How are you rendering plain text? Thanks!

**Update: Using the answer below works. So the solution is to set render layout to false. And proceed to use sometext.html.erb instead of sometext.text.erb**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't render the layout:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

This will follow the convention to find your view, so it will expect your view to be at `app/views/my_controller/your_action.html.erb`